# eAccelerator will only show Cached Scripts: 1

Tags: php, caching, eaccelerator

I'm trying to reduce the load of PHP on my website and increase the speed with PHP caching.

I've currently got eAccelerator installed and running with my PHP(according to php-v & phpinfo), however when I run phpInfo I see this:

```
eAccelerator
eAccelerator support enabled
Version 0.9.6
Caching Enabled true
Optimizer Enabled true
Check mtime Enabled true
Memory Size 16,777,176 Bytes
Memory Available 16,774,640 Bytes
Memory Allocated 2,536 Bytes
Cached Scripts 1
Removed Scripts 0
```

No mater how long I wait, it'll only have 1 Cached Script.
I've tried a number of Versions. The latest one, the 0.5.3, nothing seems to work.

cPanel Says I'm running PHP using CGI, but phpInfo says my Server API is: CGI/FastCGI
I have a cgi-fcgi section in PhpInfo also.

What do I need to do to enable caching? I've tried xCache and APC with no success either.

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to the installation and configuration instructions of the product you want to use. If you think it's a cPanel configuration issue please contact your cPanel support.

Comment: Do you have a php with the suhoshin patch ? IIRC it prevents any op-code caching